# mariadb 11.0.2 crashed without error message

Tags: mariadb, crash

I am using MariaDB 11.0.2, upgraded from 10.5.x.
some of the servers is good and working fast.
the other one, is not.

It start crashing after upgrade, but without an error message. when running as a service or when running directly in bash at root.

```
$ mariadbd
mariadbd: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2023-07-04  0:42:07 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What I tried:

- reinstall MariaDB  again
- took server from backup, restore, and restart
- restore a copy from working server via mariadb-backup
- change the directory of  data and start the server (work one time, but not the second one)

where to start ?

Debian 12, kernel 6.1.0-9

Thanks for all.

Comment: If you started as a service, `journalctl -n 80 -u mariadb.service` will be the logs. Or `sudo -u mysql mariadbd` if running in the foreground. Or look at `sudo -u mysql my_print_defaults --mysqld` for logfile if set. Doing a set of actions without seeing a case is a fragile way to conduct systems adminstration.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried to locate the logs from /var/log/syslog and  from mysql log-error, but these logs was empty. at the end - I was upgraded to 11.1 RC and it start working. I do not know why but it just works without problems.